# Can not set default template in openoffice for Mac

Tags: openoffice, openoffice-calc, templates

The following reference attempts to explain how to set a new default template for Calc.

https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Changing_the_Default_Template

[image]

I have followed the directions but there is no "Set as Default" button:

[image]

So .. how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those directions are for LibreOffice.  Use [the Apache OpenOffice directions](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOoAuthors_User_Manual/Writer_Guide/Setting_a_default_template) instead.

To get to the `Organize` menu, I went to `File -> New -> Templates and Documents` and clicked the `Organize` button.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I successfully set my custom template as the default template on `MacOS 14.3.1` and `OpenOffice 4.1.15`:

1. `File`
2. `Templates`
3. `Organize`
4. Double-left-click on `My Templates` in the **LEFT COLUMN** of the dialog to expand the "folder/directory"
5. Single-left-click on `[my-template]`
6. Single-right-click on `[my-template]`
7. `Set As Default Template`

[image]